# lapply to sum columns of many data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, cluster-computing, lapply, data-manipulation

I have a large number of CSV files with x, y, value and cluster columns in one folder. I want to use lapply() to take out the value and cluster column of each file to result in one data frame with the sum for both columns of all files. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example, say, the output of `df_list %>% head %>% purrr::map( ~ head(.x))` where `df_list` is the result of reading some of the files from disk.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like below?

```
aggregate(
  cbind(value, cluster) ~ .,
  do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(pattern = "*.csv"), read.csv)),
  sum
)
```

Comment: Yes, exactly! Is it also possible to run this parallel? Normally I would use mclapply() to run parallel on 48 cores.

Comment: @Shark167 Sorry that I had no experience on `mclapply`, but you can have a try :)

Answer (score 0):

An option with `tidyverse` would be to read the csv files with `read_csv` from `readr`, row bind (`_dfr`), grouped by 'x', 'y' columns, get the `sum` of the numeric columns

```
library(purrr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")
map_dfr(files, read_csv) %>%
    group_by(x, y) %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

If we want to do this in parallel, use `future.apply`

```
library(future.apply)
future::plan(multiprocess, workers = length(files))
options(future.globals.maxSize= +Inf) 
      
out <- future.apply::future_Map(files, read_csv)
future::plan(sequential)
bind_rows(out) %>%
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or make use of `parallel`

```
ncores <- min(parallel::detectCores(), length(files))
 cl <- parallel::makeCluster(ncores, type = "SOCK")
    doSNOW::registerDoSNOW(cl)
    out2 <- foreach(i = seq_along(files),  
                   .packages = c("data.table")) %dopar%   {
          
                     fread(files[i])
           
  
      }
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
library(data.table_
rbindlist(out2)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), .(x, y)]
```

Comment: I don't think `workers = length(files)` is a good idea.  That can result in a very large number of background workers overloading the machine.  Instead, to maximize the number of workers, stick to the default, i.e. `plan(multiprocess)`.

Comment: @HenrikB you are right.  I thought about it. I would generally use `min(length(files), ncores)`